# Consuming Restful Webservice in Windows Form Application

Tags: php, winforms, web-services, rest

I am trying to consume a restful webservice written in PHP(returns JSon response) in Windows Form application. It gives some html in response saying

> This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support

Web Service

```
//Slim based php webservice   
 $app->get(
        "/books",
        function () use ($app) {
           $books[0] = array(
                    "id" => "1",
                    "name" => "lifeGoesOn" ,
                    "author" => "nomibhaii"
                );
            $books[1] = array(
                    "id" => "2",
                    "name" => "lifesaysgoodbye" ,
                    "author" => "nomibhaii"
                );
            $app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return json_encode($books);
        }
    )

;
```

C# Code : On button click I make a request but response in unexpected some html

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string response = null;
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                response = client.DownloadString("http://nomi.byethost5.com/api/index.php/books");
                if (response != "")
                {
                    resultBox.Text = response;
                }

            }

        }
```

I get this response Response :

```
    <html>
      <body>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>functiontoNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("cf92896f26e0006666f074859130bb95");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";location.href="http://nomi.byethost5.com/api/index.php/books?ckattempt=1";</script><noscript>

This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```